# Error Datepicker

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-tool-suite

Tengo un problema con el DatePicker (updateFechaTextView) al momento de seleccionar una fecha en el calendario por ejemplo 18/10/2023 en mi textView me sale 18/10/2023 pero cuando veo mi base de datos me sale 17/10/2023 , hasta ahora no encuentro la solucion , les comparto el codigo(Kotlin)

```
private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
    val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener DatePickerDialog@{ view, year, monthOfYear , dayOfMonth ->
        // Cuando el usuario selecciona una fecha, actualiza la variable de fecha y la muestra en el TextView.
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear )
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
        updateFechaTextView()

    }, year, month, day)

    datePickerDialog.show()
}
private fun updateFechaTextView() {
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    dateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    val selectedDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.time)
    fecha?.text = selectedDate
    precio?.setText("1000")
}
```

base de datos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

App:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]